# $G \simeq H \times K$ such that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ having order $m$ and $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ having order $n$

Tags: group-theory

Assume that $G$ is a group of order $mn$ such that $(m,n)=1$.
Show that $G \simeq H \times K$  such that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ having order $m$ and $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ having order $n$.

Any way to start the proof? I don't see it...

Comment: Is $G$ assumend to be abelian? If not then $G = S_3$ is not a direct product of a group of order 2 and a group of order 3.

Comment: A harder, but interesting, exercise - I think this is true for all pairs $m,n$ with $|G|=mn$ and $(m,n)=1$ if and only if $G$ is nilpotent.

Comment: There is no other assumption... So, What if $G$ is abelian?

Comment: If $G$ is nilpotent (so this also holds if $G$ is abelian) you have $G=P_1\times\cdots\times P_k$ for some $k$ where each $P_i$ has prime power order $p_i^{e_i}$ and $p_i\ne p_j$ for $i\ne j$. The order of $G$ is $mn$ and $(m,n)=1$ implies that, after reordering $P_i$ if necessary, $m=p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_r^{e_r}$ and $n=p_{r+1}^{e_{r+1}}\cdots p_k^{e_k}$ for some $r$. The subgroups you're looking for are then $H=P_1\times\cdots\times P_r$ and $K=P_{r+1}\times\cdots\times P_k$.

Answer (score 0):

Schur's theorem says that a group of order $mn$ with $(m,n)=1$ contains a abelian normal subgroup of order $n$ then it also contains a subgroup of order $m$

So for all types of groups of order $mn$, $(m,n)=1$ if the group has a abelian normal subgroup of order n or of order m then the above result is true and the proof is written below.

Say it has a abelian normal subgroup of order $n$ the it also has a subgroup of order $m$ (By Schur's theorem)
Say the subgroup of order $n$ be H and that of order $m$ be K

Now $HK=G$ as order of $HK=(O(H)*O(K))/(O(H\cap K)=mn$

Now we also know that if $G$ be a group with $H$ subgroup of $G$ and $K$ subgroup of $G$ such that $G = HK$ and $H ∩ K = {e}$, then the internal direct product is isomorphic to the external direct product, hence proving the result.

The statement that you gave is not true generally, easy counter-examples are possible.

Comment: What theorem are you referring to? This is plainly false.

Comment: I made a slight error in writing

you may see
https://books.google.co.in/books?id=LJtyhu8-xYwC&pg=PA102&lpg=PA102&dq=A+group+of+order+mn+with+(m,n)%3D1+has+a+subgroup+of+order+m&source=bl&ots=4C1kmxOx2E&sig=X72cWx8LxEkwzJQHTnAbzB1mmQk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwilsIeYj-XTAhWKro8KHZ1vB0sQ6AEIQTAF#v=onepage&q=A%20group%20of%20order%20mn%20with%20(m%2Cn)%3D1%20has%20a%20subgroup%20of%20order%20m&f=false

Answer (score 0):

The group $A_5$ has order $60$, but no nontrivial normal subgroups. So it cannot be the direct product of subgroups of order $12$ and $5$.

If $f\colon H\times K\to G$ is an isomorphism, then $f(H)$ and $f(K)$ are both normal subgroups of $G$.

Comment: This is just an example! I want a proof!

Comment: @PaoloMolina How can you prove a false statement?

Comment: Assume that it is true and reach a contradiction!

Comment: @PaoloMolina Isn't a counterexample sufficient to prove a statement is false?

Comment: Also, Who said that we are talking of normal subgroups? They don't need to be normal

Comment: Given the context, you could state/explain why $H$ is a normal subgroup of $H\times K$ (and source $A_5$'s properties). More importantly, the question was likely scoped for Abelian groups, so a mention of a solution a la the comments to the question could be helpful.

Comment: @PaoloMolina See the addition